# Implementing aws apigateway

Tags: rest, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to test an implementation of `aws apigateway` on an existing webapplication's REST endpoint on aws. This endpoint is for bulk updates using `POST/PATCH` methods

Looking into the vast and lengthy documentation on AWS site, it talk about IAM roles for authentication.

Any high-level tips on implementing API gateways will be appreciated, to get started.

Comment: If you want to avoid reading please go and watch some quick videos. I have one if you want to watch - https://youtu.be/n5XFPLo4Bbw

Answer (score 0):

Choosing IAM Role in Authorization and also Choosing Other Authorizers (Lambda or Cognito) are also optional.

Do simple Steps and you are ready.

- Create an API.
- Goto Resources>>Actions>>create Method (POST/PATCH).
- Integration Type Choose HTTP and **enter your endpoint Url**
- Resources >> Action >> Deploy API

It will deploy apigateway application and provide you Endpoint url to use.

Again:
Choosing Models, API Keys, Client Certificates, Custom Domain, Authorizers and VPC setup all are optional.

Its simple and easy.